# Quick notation questions about linear regression: $Y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + e$

Tags: probability, notation, regression

> I came across an example in my book and got confused [see screenshot below]. I know my notation is overkill but I just want to make sure my understanding is clear.

**Question 1:** Is it correct that $(x_1, Y_1) = (0.5, 15.0)$?

**Question 2:** Would you ever use the notation $Y_{.5}$ where the input level is in the notation? This seems like a bad idea to me because there could be multiple observations at the $x=.5$ input level. Therefore, regression notation should always be $Y_1, Y_2, ... $

**Question 3:** In the book problem is it correct that $(x_3, Y_3) = (1.5, 16.5)$? If not, what is the correct way to identify this data pair?

**Question 4:** In the red box in the screenshot, an example for the first data pair $ (x_1, Y_1) = (.5,15.0) $... let's say that $d=.1$ and therefore one block is $.1$ miles. Then

$$Y = Y_1 = 15.0 = Y_{1(1)} + Y_{1(2)}... + Y_{1\left(\frac{.5}{.1}\right)} $$

$$= Y_{1(1)} + ... + Y_{1(5)} = 15$$

which I know is way overkill on notation but I just want to be clear. There are $5$ blocks to traverse. Is the above correct?

**Question 5:** Is the following correct?

$$Var(Y) = Var(Y_1) = Var(Y_{1(1)} + ... + Y_{1(5)}) = 5 Var(Y_{1(1)}) = 5 \sigma^2$$

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question $1$ and $3$ are correct. In question 2 one cannot use the notation $Y_.5$ instead one should use $Y_1$. In question $4$ although they have written $Y_i, i = 1,...,x\backslash d$ what they really mean is that one has to go till the last block with $i^{th}$ position such that it is given by $x\backslash d$. Therefore $$Y = Y_1+Y_2+Y_3+Y_4+Y_5$$ as asked in question $4.$ The answer to question $5$ is similar.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that does help. What if $x/d$ is not an integer? For example what if $x = 4.1$ and $d=1$? The thing about $Y = Y_1+Y_2+Y_3+Y_4+Y_5$ is that each $Y_i$ should have the same variance but I'm not sure about $Y_5$ since it's not a full block.

Comment: why do you think $Y_5 $ is not a full block? Also according to the example in the screenshot, what I can see is that no matter what $d $ you take it will always represent the length of the block and it will be same for all the blocks. Therefore even if $x\backslash d$ is not an integer, $Y_i$ will have the same variance.